# Issue with graphQL in nodejs , null returned for customised type in graphQL

Tags: node.js, graphql

I am currently exploring graphQL with nodejs, I m trying to build a simple example as below:

```
var express = require('express');
var graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
var { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

var schema = buildSchema(`
type Query {
getUser(jid: String ): [User],
albums:[Album],
}

type User{
name:String,
image:String,
albums:[Album]
}

type Album{
name:String,
image:String
}

`);

class Album {
    constructor() { }
    name() { return 'ablum name' }
    image() { return 'image url' }
}

class User {
    constructor(jid) {
        this.jid = jid;
        console.log(this.jid);

    }
    ablums() {

        return [new Album, new Album];

    };
    name() {
        console.log(this.jid);
        return "name";
    }
    image() { return "url"; }
}

var root = {

    getUser: function ({ jid }) {
        return [new User(jid), new User(jid)];
    },

};

var app = express();
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: root,
    graphiql: true,
}));
app.listen(4000);
console.log('Running a GraphQL API server at localhost:4000/graphql');
```

I m expecting a JSON result with two User Arrays , each of it contain another two albums array which contain it's name and image. However I have got null in the Album field which should show an arrays of two albums with name and image field.

```
{
"data": {
"getUser": [
  {
    "name": "name of abc is michael",
    "image": "url",
    "albums": null
  },
  {
    "name": "name of abc is michael",
    "image": "url",
    "albums": null
  }
 ]
}
}
```

Please help! I am completely new to graphQL and I think it is a very useful technology!

Comment: Please edit your question to properly indent your code. It's difficult to read, which makes it difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo on your user class, your method is called ablums yet your query is looking for a method / property called albums, which doesn't exist, hence returning null.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example using Node for an existing server using Hasura (which btw is awesome). This following code is just to get a response in JSON from a Hasura/Postgres schema (or whatever GraphQL server). Once you have the data into a variable so you could serve it using express. I'm working on that, but there might be several examples out there. I can share it later. Check out Hasura subscriptions as well, it uses out-of-the-box realtime communications, so every change on the database is sent to the client. Here is a link: https://github.com/hasura/nodejs-graphql-subscriptions-boilerplate

On this example, just change the gql query to match your schema and query.

Hope this helps.. regards!

```
var { ApolloClient } = require('apollo-client');
var { InMemoryCache } = require('apollo-cache-inmemory');
var { HttpLink } = require('apollo-link-http');
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const link = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8081/v1/graphql/', fetch: fetch
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link
});
const gql = require('graphql-tag');

var query = gql`
query planeacion {
    lineas (where: { linea : { _eq: "123" }}){
    descripcion
    linea
  }
}

`
client
  .query({
    query: query
  })
  .then(result => console.log(JSON.stringify(result.data)));
```